# Facebook fitness run with custom unit

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement Facebook share to my fitness apps to share information like route, speed, distance, etc.

Currently I am using the Facebook Fitness Run Action to achieve this and I got the following.

[image]

Now, I would like to include more information in this share post just like what Nike do:

[image]

I am confused and I do not know where to add a "custom unit" like the "NikeFuel" in the above image.

I have read the Facebook document but still not sure what should I do.

Anyone can lead me a little? Thank you so much.

============== Update 1 =================

I am trying to implement it using the following code but it doesn't work

```
ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder objectfatburn = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
          .putString("og:type", "fitness.unit")
          .putString("og:title", "Fat Burn")
          .putString("fitness:name", "fatburn");

  // Create an object
  ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()

          .putString("og:type", "fitness.course")
          .putString("og:title", "FitnessApp")


          .putString("fitness:duration:value", (workout.duration / 1000) + "")
          .putString("fitness:duration:units", "s")

          .putString("fitness:distance:value", String.format("%.2f", workout.current_distance / 1000f))
          .putString("fitness:distance:units", "km")

          .putString("fitness:speed:value", (workout.current_distance / (workout.duration / 1000)) + "")
          .putString("fitness:speed:units", "m/s")

          .putString("fitness:custom_unit_energy:value", 100 + "")
          .putString("fitness:custom_unit_energy:units", "fatburn");


  for(int i = 0; i < workout.location_record.size();i++ ){

      object.putDouble("fitness:metrics["+i+"]:location:latitude", workout.location_record.get(i).getLat());
      object.putDouble("fitness:metrics["+i+"]:location:longitude",workout.location_record.get(i).getLong());

      if(i == 0) {
          object.putString("fitness:metrics["+i+"]:timestamp", workout.timestamp - workout.duration + "");
      }else {

          if (i == workout.location_record.size() - 1) {
object.putString("fitness:metrics["+i+"]:timestamp", workout.timestamp + "");
          }
      }
  }

  // Create an action
  ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
          .setActionType("fitness.runs")
          .putObject("unit", objectfatburn.build())
          .putObject("course", object.build())
          .build();

  // Create the content
  ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
          .setPreviewPropertyName("course")
          .setAction(action)
          .build();
```

====================== Update 2 ========================

I have tried to host the following and try to use it for sharing

```
<html><head>
    <title>OG Sample Object - Sample Course</title>

     <meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxx"> 
     <meta property="og:type" content="fitness.unit"> 
     <meta property="og:title" content="Fat Burn"> 
     <meta property="og:image" content="https://sstatic.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png"> 

     <meta property="fitness:name" content="fatburn">

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/app.css">
</head>
<body>
```

and i have added the following code to add my custom unit but..... it doesn't work...

```
  .putString("fitness:speed:value", (workout.current_distance / (workout.duration / 1000)) + "")
  .putString("fitness:speed:units", "m/s")

  .putString("fitness:custom_unit_energy:value", 100 + "")
  .putString("fitness:custom_unit_energy:units", "http://xxxxxx/fatburn.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/fitness.unit/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/fitness.course/#properties
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-api#objectapi-creatingapp

I think `fitness.unit` as `fitness:custom_unit_energy` used in `fitness.course` might do the trick. Otherwise, check the OpenGraph details for the NikeFuel example to probably see why properties they used.

As I understand the docs, the unit object must have a **public url** ("app-owned object") where it's available ( I don't think it's enough to create it dynamically), meaning that you should host it somewhere on your server:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{your_app_id}" /> 
<meta property="og:type"   content="fitness.unit" /> 
<meta property="og:url"    content="Put your own URL to the object here" /> 
<meta property="og:title"  content="Fat Burn" /> 
<meta property="og:image"  content="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" />
```

Comment: Thank you Tobi and I am trying the same direction, I have updated my question and I am not sure what I am missing

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Tobi...but I am still struggling.... I have updated my question and I am hosting the object myself. I have read the Facebook doc but they are not clear to me... am I going the right direction in my update?